# Could not find elementById on mat-card-content

Tags: angular, dom, angular-material, chart.js

Having a canvas on the page is no problem to find it by id:

```
<canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
document.getElementById("chart")
```

everything fine. but if i wrap it in a mat-card i could not find it anymore:

```
    <mat-card>
      <mat-card-title>My title</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>My sub title</mat-card-subtitle>
      <mat-card-content>
        <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

and this results with:

```
document.getElementById("chart")
null
```

any idea why?

Comment: any errors in console? can you please add a [mcve] to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably when you try to get it, it is not on the page. Components are javascript objects. So you need to get element after it loaded. I don't recommend the below solution. You should do it when component initialized.

**Try this to validate my assumption:**

```
setTimeout(() => {  
    console.log(document.getElementById("chart"))  
}, 5000); // 5 seconds to make sure
```

Comment: i switched to https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit and it was fine

Comment: I don't have much idea about angular. Great that worked.

Comment: The `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook should work as this hook is called after the component's view has been initialised.